# Jmeter Recording Issue- Application is not loading while recording

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to record the jmeter script using Apache JMeter HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, but the application(https://) is not loading in the browser. it was working fine before. I gave the correct proxy settings and import the jmeter certificate in the browser.
I can record all other sites  but not the site that is I need to record.

where should the issue? how I can solve this?

Thanks
Sree

Answer (score 0):

If anything goes wrong first of all take a look at [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). If it doesn't tell much - [increase logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for the component's you're using, in your case for the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), it can be done by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick up the change.

Also be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blazemeter-the-continuous/mbopgmdnpcbohhpnfglgohlbhfongabi?hl=en), in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.